# Eslint not outputting errors to the console

Tags: node.js, eslint

I'm running eslint 1.9.0 on Windows on the following test file

```
var foo = (3 * 4);
```

The command I am using (from the same directory as the file) is

```
eslint test.js
```

However nothing is outputted to the console. If I understand correctly, it should output a few errors here such as [no-extra-parens](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-extra-parens.html) which is on by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from version 1.0.0 ESLint doesn't enable any of the rules by default. In order to enable "recommended" rules, you should create a .eslintrc file in the root of your project and add the following line to it:

```
{
  "extends": "eslint:recommended"
}
```

That will enable all of the rules that are marked as "recommended" on [this page](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/).

Comment: Ugh what an unreasonable default. Thanks for pointing it out! :)